# Load tensorflow dataset directly from cache object

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've built a `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline to transform my data into tensors and towards the end of my pipeline, I'm caching the data to speed up subsequent iterations through the data.

`tf.data.Dataset` has the `.cache` function to do this, but in my training script, I'd like to load the dataset object directly from the cache object, rather than needing all the code to build the pipeline.

Below is a watered down example that generates a dataset of images, and caches it to `my_cache`.    In another setting (one that doesn't require the details of the pipeline), can I create a dataset object using only `my_cache`?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Define some complicated tf.data pipeline
def complicated_data_generator():
    """
    Generates samples inputs,target of the form
    inputs:   ( [32,32,3], [32,32,3] )
    targets:  ( [32,32,3], )
    """
    for i in range(10):
        inputs = (np.random.rand(32,32,3).astype(np.float32),
                  np.random.rand(32,32,3).astype(np.float32))
        target = (np.random.rand(32,32,3).astype(np.float32), )
        yield inputs,target
tspec = tf.TensorSpec(shape=(32,32,3), dtype=tf.float32)
output_signature = (tspec,tspec),(tspec,)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(complicated_data_generator,output_signature=output_signature)

@tf.function
def add_feature(inputs,target):
    return inputs+(inputs[0],),target
ds = ds.map(add_feature)
ds = ds.shuffle(5)

# Set up cache file
ds = ds.cache('my_cache')

# Loop over data once to cache
for x,y in ds:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case, I found the following works where you initialize from a dummy generator.  I did need to supply the expected shapes of the data using `tf.TensorSpec`

```py
dum_gen = lambda : None 
tspec = tf.TensorSpec(shape=(32,32,3), dtype=tf.float32)
output_signature = (tspec,tspec,tspec),(tspec,)
ds_new = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(dum_gen,output_signature=output_signature)
ds_new = ds_new.cache('my_cache')
```

Then `ds_new` can be iterated over.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be accepted, I can only upvote.

Comment: Thanks! Also note in newer versions, tensorflow implemented `tf.data.Dataset.save` which makes saving and loading slow datasets even easier.